# Does local flatness imply a local Euclidean metric?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, mathematical-physics

I stumbled upon something that confused me recently regarding topics in differential geometry.

From what I understand, one of the key parts of the definition of a manifold is that it is locally flat or isomorphic to Euclidean space.

However, does this mean that locally, it's metric is also Euclidean?

The reason I ask is because what if you have a manifold with intrinsic curvature, say a 2 sphere. A 2 sphere is locally flat but I also know that it's metric is not Euclidean.

Can someone clarify for me?

Perhaps the mistake I am making is that they have nothing to do with one another, and that being locally isomorphic to Euclidean space doesn't imply a Euclidean metric.

Comment: One can always find coordinates in which a Riemannian metric approximates the Euclidean metric up to second-order. The second-order error term is known as the Riemannian curvature tensor. That is, $$g_{ik} = \delta_{ik} - \frac{1}{3} R_{ijk\ell} x^j x^{\ell}$$ where $R$ is the curvature tensor.

Comment: The problem is that the word "isomorphic" has different meanings in different contexts, and it's best to use less ambiguous terms. First, you should review the definitions of a manifold and a Riemannian manifold and understand the difference. A manifold is locally *diffeomorphic* to Euclidean space. A manifold has no metric on it. A Riemannian manifold is a smooth manifold with a Riemannian metric. If the Riemannian manifold is locally *isometric* to Euclidean space, then its metric is indeed Euclidean.

Answer (score 2):

"Locally flat" means the metric (which is an additional structure on top of a manifold's differential structure) has 0 curvature.

Any manifold is "locally Euclidean" meaning that it is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. This is what I assume you're referring to in the manifold definition. This does not refer to any metric structure.

The standard 2-sphere is thought of as a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$, from which it is assumed to inherit a standard metric. With this structure it becomes a *Riemannian* manifold, whose curvature you can compute (it is not locally flat).

I hope that helps explain some of the terminology.

Comment: Okay I think I understand a little bit better now. I was using the terms locally Euclidean and locally flat identically.